# OUTER APPLY in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, cross-apply, outer-apply

I want to apply a column to a list of users where I pull the latest sign in date .
Traditionally I would do something like this:

```
SELECT U.* , O.* FROM Users.Users U 
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT .. FROM .. Events.Events E WHERE E.UserId = U.UserId) O
```

However BigQuery doesn't seem to recognize the Outer Apply keywords. What Am I doing wrong, is there a substitute for above?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make your question much clearer.

Answer (score 3):

This approach seems to work:

```sql
SELECT U.*, O.*
FROM Users.Users U
LEFT JOIN UNNEST((
  SELECT array_agg(STRUCT(...))
  FROM Events.Events E
  WHERE E.UserId = U.UserId
)) ON TRUE
```

Of course, in your simplified case, you don't actually need `OUTER APPLY` (or standard SQL `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`). You'd just use an ordinary `LEFT JOIN`. I'm assuming your outer applied derived table does something more fancy that requires this operator.