# BigQuery alternatives to OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In MS SQL Server i have a query like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM tableA
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tableB 
WHERE tableB.dateTimeColumn < tableA.dateTimeColumn ORDER BY tableB.dateTimeColumn DESC)
```

How i can have the same result in BigQuery due to the lack of OUTER APPLY?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244399/outer-apply-in-bigquery this should help

Answer (score 0):

Per this [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244399/outer-apply-in-bigquery), your query would be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM tableB
  WHERE tableB.dateTimeColumn < tableA.dateTimeColumn
  ORDER BY tableB.dateTimeColumn DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS tableB ON true;
```